# This is a Google App Script question dealing with two issues, one of speed and the other how to handle a method

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

**The spreadsheet has 14 locations and that list will grow over time. Each location is on its own sheet. This is my variable declaration:**

```
        function locationSearch(searchTerm, selectedLocation) {
          if (searchTerm == '') { return };
        
          const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
          searchResults = [];
          const schoolLocation = [
            "ALTUS_ACADEMY", "ANNUNCIATA", "EPIPHANY", "GRACE", "HOLY_FAMILY",
            "INNOVATIVE_SCHOLARS", "ISLAMIC_CC_OF_IL", "JOSEPHINUM_HS",
            "MATERNITY_BVM", "POPE_FRANCIS", "PROVIDENCE", "PUI_TAK", "ST_AILBE",
            "ST_BORGIA", "ST_ELIZABETH", "ST_PAUL"
          ];
        
          const schoolALTUSACADEMY = ss.getSheetByName('ALTUS_ACADEMY');
          const schoolANNUNCIATA = ss.getSheetByName('ANNUNCIATA');
          const schoolEPIPHANY = ss.getSheetByName('EPIPHANY');
          const schoolGRACE = ss.getSheetByName('GRACE');
          const schoolHOLYFAMILY = ss.getSheetByName('HOLY_FAMILY');
          const iNNOVATIVESCHOLARS = ss.getSheetByName('INNOVATIVE_SCHOLARS');
          const schoolISLAMICCCOFIL = ss.getSheetByName('ISLAMIC_CC_OF_IL');
          const schoolJOSEPHINUMHS = ss.getSheetByName('JOSEPHINUM_HS');
          const schoolPOPE_FRANCIS = ss.getSheetByName('POPE_FRANCIS');
          const schoolMATERNITYBVM = ss.getSheetByName('MATERNITY_BVM');
          const schoolPROVIDENCE = ss.getSheetByName('PROVIDENCE');
          const schoolPUITAK = ss.getSheetByName('PUI_TAK');
          const schoolSTAILBE = ss.getSheetByName('ST_AILBE');
          const schoolSTBORGIA = ss.getSheetByName('ST_BORGIA');
          const schoolSTELIZABETH = ss.getSheetByName('ST_ELIZABETH');
          const schoolSTPAUL = ss.getSheetByName('ST_PAUL');
        
          var schALTUSACADEMY = schoolALTUSACADEMY.getDataRange().getValues().slice(1);
          var schANNUNCIATA = schoolANNUNCIATA.getDataRange().getValues().slice(1);
          var schEPIPHANY = schoolEPIPHANY.getDataRange().getValues().slice(1);
          var schGRACE = schoolGRACE.getDataRange().getValues().slice(1);
          var schHOLYFAMILY = schoolHOLYFAMILY.getDataRange().getValues().slice(1);
          var schiNNOVATIVESCHOLARS = iNNOVATIVESCHOLARS.getDataRange().getValues().slice(1);
          var schISLAMICCCOFIL = schoolISLAMICCCOFIL.getDataRange().getValues().slice(1);
          var schJOSEPHINUMHS = schoolJOSEPHINUMHS.getDataRange().getValues().slice(1);
          var schMATERNITYBVM = schoolMATERNITYBVM.getDataRange().getValues().slice(1);
          var schPOPEFRANCIS = schoolPOPE_FRANCIS.getDataRange().getValues().slice(1);
          var schPROVIDENCE = schoolPROVIDENCE.getDataRange().getValues().slice(1);
          var schPUITAK = schoolPUITAK.getDataRange().getValues().slice(1);
          var schSTAILBE = schoolSTAILBE.getDataRange().getValues().slice(1);
          var schSTBORGIA = schoolSTBORGIA.getDataRange().getValues().slice(1);
          var schSTELIZABETH = schoolSTELIZABETH.getDataRange().getValues().slice(1);
          var schSTPAUL = schoolSTPAUL.getDataRange().getValues().slice(1);
        
          var schLocation = [
            schALTUSACADEMY, schANNUNCIATA, schEPIPHANY, schGRACE, schHOLYFAMILY,
            schiNNOVATIVESCHOLARS, schISLAMICCCOFIL, schJOSEPHINUMHS, schMATERNITYBVM,
            schPOPEFRANCIS, schPROVIDENCE, schPUITAK, schSTAILBE, schSTBORGIA, schSTELIZABETH,
            schSTPAUL
          ];
        
          var all_Locations = schALTUSACADEMY.concat(schANNUNCIATA, schEPIPHANY, schGRACE,   schHOLYFAMILY,
            schiNNOVATIVESCHOLARS, schISLAMICCCOFIL, schJOSEPHINUMHS, schMATERNITYBVM, schPOPEFRANCIS,
            schPROVIDENCE, schPUITAK, schSTAILBE, schSTBORGIA, schSTELIZABETH, schSTPAUL);
          //var loc  = lSearch(searchTerm);
```

Is there a better way of getting these sheets into memory?

The second problem getting this method to return the correct value

```
     for (var i = 0; i < dataBase.length; i++) { //[x] select the row to be searchedfor (var x =   0; x < dataBase[0].length; x++) {
```

```
                if (dataBase[i][x] == searchTerm) { //[x] search the row for search term
                  var item = {};
                  item.entryMadeby = dataBase[i][1];
                  item.checkinDate = dataBase[i][2];
                  item.productCode = dataBase[i][3];
                  item.description = dataBase[i][4];
                  item.location = function () {
```

**This portion of the code calls a function that  return a location**
lSearch(searchTerm)
return
};**
item.checkoutdate = dataBase[i][6];
//Logger.log(item);
searchResults.push(item);
//Logger.log((i+1));
//console.log(item);
//console.log(item.location());
}
}
}

```
} else {for (var index = 0; index \< schLocation.length; index++) {dataBase = schLocation\[index\];
```

```
              for (var i = 0; i < dataBase.length; i++) { //[x] select the row to be search
                for (var x = 0; x < dataBase[0].length; x++) {
            
                  if (dataBase[i][x] == searchTerm) { //[x] search the row for search term
                    var item = {
                      'entryMadeby': dataBase[i][1],
                      'checkinDate': dataBase[i][2],
                      'productCode': dataBase[i][3],
                      'description': dataBase[i][4],
                      'location': function () {
                        lSearch(searchTerm)
                        return
                      },
                      'checkoutdate': dataBase[i][6]
                    };
                    searchResults.push(item);
                    //console.log(item.location());
            
                  }
                }
              }
            }
   }//console.log(searchResults);return searchResults;}
```

Obvisoly I am new to GAS, that said I have been reading, testing and youtubing to move this spreadsheet from excel to GAS. These are the last steps need.  As you can see I attemping to reduce the number of times the spreadsheets gets called. Each sheet gets pull into an array before the array is loop not spreadsheet. This makes sense as a best practice but is thier a better way? The object called Item solve the problem of getting search results  but the method is not working correctly. It return undefine always.  Beside the method handling code is working.

just slow.  The priority for me is getting method handling to work.

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Please ask only [one question per post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/222741). [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75061190/edit) this question so that it is focused on one problem only, and post a [new question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) for the second part.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a better way of getting these sheets into memory?

Use `Array` methods such as `.map()` to make the code more manageable, like this:

```js
function test() {
  const sheetNames = [
    'ALTUS_ACADEMY', 'ANNUNCIATA', 'EPIPHANY', 'GRACE', 'HOLY_FAMILY',
    'INNOVATIVE_SCHOLARS', 'ISLAMIC_CC_OF_IL', 'JOSEPHINUM_HS',
    'MATERNITY_BVM', 'POPE_FRANCIS', 'PROVIDENCE', 'PUI_TAK', 'ST_AILBE',
    'ST_BORGIA', 'ST_ELIZABETH', 'ST_PAUL',
  ];
  const data = mergeSheetData_(sheetNames);
  console.log(data);
}


/**
* Gets sheets listed in sheetNames and merges their data into a 2D array
* where every row starts with the name of the sheet it came from.
*
* @param {String[]} sheetNames The names of the sheets to process.
* @return {String[][]} A 2D array that contains sheet names and data.
*/
function mergeSheetData_(sheetNames) {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const data3D = sheetNames
    .map(sheetName => ss
      .getSheetByName(sheetName)
      .getDataRange()
      .getValues()
      .slice(1)
      .map(row => [sheetName, ...row])
    );
  let result = [];
  data3D.forEach(table => result = result.concat(table));
  return result;
}
```

Comment: The array allData is empty even after replacing data with alldata "data3D.forEach(table => alldata.concat(table)";